# Adding second table field to report causes report to go blank - Crystal Reports 14.1.2.1121 using SQL Server Database source

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report pulling all fields from a single SQL Server table that works well. I need to add a second table to pull additional data, but doing so causes the entire report to go blank and number of records to drop to 0, from 242 without the added field from the second report. I have no grouping in the report either.

Reviewing Database Expert Links I see multiple links between the two tables, but the field in question, (CUSTPO_27, a String field), does not appear in the original table and therefore has no link. The field needs to be in the Details section of the report along with the data from the original table.

I have run Verify Database and get the "The database is up to date" message.

Running Dependency Checker finds no errors, even with the troublesome field added.

I am fairly new to Crystal Reports, but feel like I am missing a step to be able to see the second table field in the report, so any insight or direction would be greatly appreciated.

I would be happy to add code, but I don't see where to view the code in Crystal, (again, I am a newbie!)

Answer (score 0):

Adding that field probably forced Crystal to join to a new table, and that join failed to find a matching record.  So check your join logic.

Comment: As I continued troubleshooting I did learn that the location of the links is important in Database Expert and have since move the table order, which now populates all data from the original table, but the added field from the second table is blank.  If I join tables in Crystal will that impact the tables in SQL? (Like I said, I am a newbie).  I don't want to risk any table changes in SQL.  Thanks for your quick response!

Answer (score 0):

Crystal doesn't update your database. It's Read Only.

Comment: Of course, don't know what I was worried about!